How to make a clone of shared_ptr value given that shared_ptr encompasses abstract class?
This is a project from university, I have to make a "Paint"-like application and now I am stuck at making copying and pasting.
shape is an abstract class from which other real shapes like Rectangle and Circle are inherited.
std::shared_ptr<shape> m_selectedShape = nullptr;
std::shared_ptr<shape> m_copiedShape = nullptr;

//...
else if ((event->key() == Qt::Key_C) && (event->modifiers() == Qt::ControlModifier)){
      if(m_selectedShape != nullptr){
          m_copiedShape = m_selectedShape;
      }
      update();
}
else if ((event->key() == Qt::Key_V) && (event->modifiers() == Qt::ControlModifier)){
      if(m_copiedShape != nullptr){
           //How?
      }
      update();
}
//...

I tried using make_shared but as the shared_ptr are shape, which is an abstract class, I can not.

Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern, it is one of the ways to do it.

You probably have to add a "clone" (or make_copy) method to your abstract base class shape, e.g. `virtual std::shared_ptr clone() = 0;


I tried using make_shared but as the shared_ptr are shape, which is an
abstract class, I can not.

You can still use std::make_shared to create an object of a derived class, and "give" it to the shared_ptr to abstract base to manage.
General example showing this idea:
#include <memory>

// Abstract base:
struct A {
    virtual ~A() {}
    virtual void m() = 0;
};

// Derived:
struct B : public A {
    virtual ~B() {}
    void m() override {}
};

int main() {
    // Create a derived instance and let a shared_ptr to base manage it:
    std::shared_ptr<A> p = std::make_shared<B>();
}

Live demo
You can use this concept to achieve what you need:

Add a pure virtual cloning method to your abstract base, that will return a std::shared_ptr to base (std::shared_ptr<shape>).
Then in each derived class override you can use std::make_shared as shown above to create a concrete object of the derived class (as a clone of the current one) and return it as a std::shared_ptr<shape>.


Example for a clone method
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Shape
{
public:
    virtual ~Shape() = default;
    virtual void Draw() const = 0; // Draw should not modify members, so const

    // Add A Clone method to your Shape to make copies
    virtual std::shared_ptr<Shape> Clone() const = 0; // Copy should not modify orignal so const too
};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Circle class with appropiate copy constructors (and deleted move constructors)

class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
    Circle() = default;

    explicit Circle(int radius) :
        m_radius{radius}
    {
    }

    // A copy constructor to make copies
    Circle(const Circle& other) :
        m_radius{other.m_radius}
    {
    }

    Circle& operator=(const Circle& other)
    {
        if (&other != this)
        {
            m_radius = other.m_radius;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Circle(Circle&&) = delete;
    Circle& operator=(const Circle&&) = delete;

    void Draw() const override
    {
        std::cout << "Circle, radius = " << m_radius << "\n";
    }

    // Implement the Clone method to make copies
    std::shared_ptr<Shape> Clone() const override
    {
        // use copy constructor
        return std::make_shared<Circle>(*this);
    }

private:
    int m_radius{1};
};


class Square : public Shape
{
public:
    explicit Square(int size) :
        m_size{size}
    {
    };

    Square(const Square& other) :
        m_size{other.m_size}
    {
    }

    Square& operator=(const Square& other)
    {
        if (&other != this)
        {
            m_size = other.m_size;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Square(Square&&) = delete;
    Square& operator=(const Square&&) = delete;

    std::shared_ptr<Shape> Clone() const override
    {
        // use copy constructor
        return std::make_shared<Square>(*this);
    }

    void Draw() const override
    {
        std::cout << "Square, size = " << m_size << "\n";
    }

private:
    int m_size{1};
};


int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Shape> circle1 = std::make_shared<Circle>(1);
    std::shared_ptr<Shape> circle2 = std::make_shared<Circle>(2);


    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Shape>> shapes{circle1,circle2};

    shapes.emplace_back(std::make_shared<Square>(3));

    // Add some copies to shapes
    shapes.emplace_back(circle1->Clone());
    shapes.emplace_back(circle2->Clone());

    for(const auto& shape : shapes)
    {
        shape->Draw();
    }

}

